# How to incorporate jQuery into react app?

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app and for the responsive menu I need it to accept jQuery so that I can use menu toggle for the menu. I am new to react and when I add plain jQuery into react, it shows an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

function Menu() {
  return (
  <div className="head row">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 top-left">
          <Link to ="/"><img className="img-responsive mainlogo"  src={require('./Header-logo.png')} alt="logo"/></Link>
          <Link className="peaks" to="/">SPORT</Link>
          <div className="mobile-menu hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div className="icon"><Link className="toggle-menu" to="#"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></Link></div>
            <div className="text">MENU</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  (".toggle-menu").click(function(){
  (".menu").toggle();
  });

  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: I found react and jQuery doesn't work well together. I recommend implement your functionality you want in react style. i.e. using flux/redux.

Comment: What's the error? Update your question with the stack trace.

Comment: The error is because he missed the $ I guess...

Comment: DOM manipulation using jQuery is not a good idea because as object changes its state, ReactDom re-renders the DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You use ES6 I can see, so I'd advise consequently use classes and extend `Component` object. In general, when you really must use JQuery with React, you can do it that way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Menu extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //some JQuery code - runs after render function
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="head row">
      <div className="container">
        {/* your HTML that I'm skipping */}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

export default Menu;
```